# Authorization Issue - anonymous users can't access .jpeg or .css

Tags: asp.net, forms, forms-authentication

I have this on my web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="Venues.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

I only want to allow authenticated users to my pages. The problem is, the first time that I go to the login page, I don't have any images or styles on my page. I think this is because I denied access to the `.jpeg` and `.css` files.
I think I can solve this issue in IIS, but I'm just in Dev. I only have VS 2008 and no IIS.

Is it possible for me to allow access to the `imgs` dir for the anonymous user in the web.config?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could allow certain directories (directly under `<configuration>`):

```
<location path="images">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Also you would probably need to include WebResource.axd

```
<location path="WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a known bug in Visual Studio - when you're not using IIS, visual studio mistakenly blocks the CSS file on the login page.

See here:
[blog post from tomtech999](http://tomtech999.wordpress.com/2006/06/28/advanced-forms-authentication/)

It should be OK when you run in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, if you want Microsoft's ReportViewer control to work on your web page, you need to add this:

```
<location path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

This was a problem for me while attempting to get the 2010 version of report viewer to work.  (Fortunately, it only took 7 billion years to uncover the source of the problem.)