# Can't access css after adding <authentication> to web.config

Tags: asp.net, authentication, config

The webpage that I am creating can't access the CSS file.

Take a look at my webconfig:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <location path="css">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="60"/>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I found some answer here:

[Authorization Issue - anonymous users can't access .jpeg or .css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811396/authorization-issue-anonymous-users-cant-access-jpeg-or-css)

But when I tried to put

```
<location path="css">
```

on top of 'system.web' it didn't work. Please help me fix this. Thanks for all your help guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location tag has to be a direct child of configuration

Put this under your existing `<system.web>`

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
   ...
   </system.web>
   <location path="css">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please check my edit, I edit my webconfig but I got this error: 'It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.'

Comment: Do not copy all your elements. You only need to set the authorization. Authentication remains part of your main `<system.web>`. You will also need an appropriate `<authorization>` tag there to block unauthenticated users.

Answer (score 2):

as you are using `<authentication mode="Forms">` and `protection="All"` so you can't access any file other than `loginUrl` without login.

If you want to access any file or folder without login you should tell this in you web.config file as follows

```
  <location path="file_name">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Or if you want any folder to be accessible without login then you should be using this as follow

```
<location path="folder_name">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

The tag **`<allow users="*" />`** works for you. It allows the user to access that path without login.
Here are some good links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692%28v=vs.100%29.aspx